# Adding oracle username/user_id to title in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus, title

I need to add the userid at the right for the btitle. But I only get **USER**??
this is the query I used.

```
BTITLE LEFT report_date CENTER 'Page: ' FORMAT 999 SQL.PNO-
RIGHT USER
/
```

[image]

Comment: The system-maintained values must be prefixed with `SQL.` There are five such values, documented in the **Terms** section, *variable* subsection, first paragraph, here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve048.htm#SQPUG131

Answer (score 0):

It is `SQL.USER` you should use:

```
SQL> BTITLE LEFT report_date CENTER 'Page: ' FORMAT 999 SQL.PNO- RIGHT SQL.USER /
SQL> select * From dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
         1 a              b





report_date                        Page:    1-                            SCOTT/
    
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you @Littlefoot. Got it!